# Session variable visible to all visitors in admin

Tags: session, admin, last-modified

I want to store last edited articles for an admin page so that if multiple administrators are editing, they can see what articles were edited recently.
My question is could I use session variable to store last edited articles id in a manor that all administrators can see it?
If not, what is the best way of doing this?

I`m using php for server side scipting.

Comment: Which server-side technologies are you using? Is this just a theoretical question?

Comment: I`m using php server-side technology

Comment: OK, I'd suggest editing your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using mysql database to store last edited articles information, in a separate table.